# How to use inverse function of Cp vs Lambda of wind turbine in MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, windturbine

I want to use inverse function. I know the value of Cp and I need to calculate Lamda and Beta through this formula. How can I do?

I think it has to do with a lookup table of Cp vs Lambda for DFIG Wind Turbine in MATLAB script format. Equation of Cp vs Lambda is attached herewith.

[image: Cp vs Lambda equation of Wind Turbine]

Comment: that looks not like a lookup table, but is plain a mathematical formula that you can just type down in a matlab function - done.

Comment: Actually I want to use it in a lookup table for controlling the Wind Turbine Generator

Comment: this is a function, not something that's part of  a lookup table, so what *exactly* are you planning to do? It's really not clear what you want to look up, by what. (and the generator has nothing to do with this, really?) (also unclear *why*, as this is a rather handy function that's not very well-mannered, so any discretization would be very unwieldy, and probably slower than direct calculation. Make sure you're actually solving a problem, not creating one)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Wind Turbine is related with Cp vs Lamda lookup table, you can see it any wind turbine basic book. I'm trying to solve it but getting some error. Here Lamda is varies from 0-20 and Beta varies from -15 to 15.

Comment: Are you trying to find an inverse function? Lookup table seems like a very bad way to evaluate a function that has fairly low computational cost. Especially one with two variables. I can't imagine speed is very important in a wind turbine application.

Comment: The above formula is wrong. In general a tool such as xfoil is used to estimate the power coefficient based on the angle of attack. Which then can be transformed into a fucntion of pitch angle and tip speed ratio. I think the question should be updated.

Comment: @aman2909 - Please read and follow the [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) as well as the "Enforcement" section at the bottom of that page. Your recent comment has been deleted and this is your one warning. Either "Be Nice" or don't reply - that applies to everyone. Thanks.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes I want to use inverse function. I know the value of Cp and I need to calculate Lamda and Beta through this formula. How can I do?

Comment: If you only know Cp there will be one or two infinite sets of solutions (or possibly none) depending on how the plane of Cp = x cuts the 3D surface.  You need at least one other variable to get an answer (might be zero, one or two answers it looks like). See this representation of the surface: https://i.imgur.com/nHnKlid.png

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too broad – OP has a question unrelated to an actual look-up table, and it's impossible – this is not an invertible function, so it's impossible to find an inverse. (Please feel invited to actually modify or state a new question that fully describes the problem you're trying to solve – so you want to find an inverse, but that's impossible on the domain you specified. What do you need that inverse for? What are other constraints? Maybe we can help solve this. The lookup table approach was (as my deleted comment explains) a distraction not helping you!)

Comment: Evaluate the function for as many points as you want, and put those values in the lookup table.

Comment: @user_1818839 that won't help find the inverse of the function – which doesn't exist. (That they're looking for an inverse is buried here in the comments. The lookup table is a red herring.)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am only going by the question, if that's a red herring, well...

Comment: @user_1818839 convinced myself that this question needs to be edited by me, because the original poster doesn't seem to get around to doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use the [interp2](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) function. You can parametrise the function either to interpolate the values or choose the nearest one.